# How can I run Spotify on a PowerPC Mac?

Tags: powerpc, power-mac, spotify, g5

Are there any version of Spotify that will run on a PowerPC Mac?

Which one(s)?

Where can I get one?

Comment: I've not long decided to go with mac having used a pc for years and decided to get myself a power mac g5.
I've tried to install spotify from various sites for this mac without success but this connection solved it all.
Well done!! joost, it's joost what the doctor ordered, many thanks

Answer (score 4):

[This site](http://web4tech.com/2012/01/04/how-to-get-spotify-to-work-on-ppc-mac/) appears to have a link to the latest version that supports PPC.  I don't have a PPC Mac, so I can't verify it.

It also mentions that this will not last forever, as Spotify will update their servers at some point and not allow that version to connect any more.

---

You can also try [Spotify-0.6.6.10.dmg](http://powerpcsoftware.com/downloads/Spotify-0.6.6.10.dmg) from [PowerPC Software Archive](http://www.powerpcsoftware.com/).

Comment: I saw that site, and as far as I can tell the dmg of the link doesn't work on PowerPC

Comment: Spotify might have already cut off support for that version.  I found threads on the Spotify forums that seem to indicate that the PPC is no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

Some anonymous do-gooder has made an older version (it updates itself to 0.6.6.10) available [right here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1932210/Spotify.app.zip). That one works fine on my Powerbook G4 PPC running 10.5.8. Contains all the main features - it's from September 2011, I believe.